# interswitch quickteller API integration in php

Tags: php, curl

i have to add interswitch payment methods in my web application but i am receiving error
following is my code

```
    function billersCategories()
    {

      $nonce=$randomNum=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 60);

    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp=$date->getTimestamp();
     // Signature
    $httpMethod = "GET";
    $url='https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/categorys';
    $clientId = "IKIA9D98ABCDEFGHIFAKEID1E09104959B9755C41E1"; 
    $clientSecretKey = "d5uAr+U8QhSv8vQtKPDIUI62327Fsfsfsf65=";
    $signatureCipher = $httpMethod."&".$url."&".$timestamp."&".$nonce."&".$clientId."&".$clientSecretKey;

    $signature = base64_encode($signatureCipher);

    $data = array("TerminalID" => "9APY556261");                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:InterswitchAuth SUtJQTUyNTBERkY1NkU5MzM2OUM0RkRBRjMxQTQ3QTg1RkNDODYyRTRDOUU=',           
        'Signature:'.$signature,            
        'Nonce:'.$nonce,            
        'Timestamp:'.$timestamp,            
        'SignatureMethod:SHA512'    
    ));                                                                                                 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

    var_dump($result);

}
```

But i am receiving following error 
"The HTTP method is not supported for this resource", i tried http method POST but same error, i am new on API can someone please help me to solve this .

Comment: I am sure the manual would help you with this problem

Comment: error code is E77 but this is not even in document no proper document and no proper support

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, fill the following
In the variable
 - $clientId
 - $clientSecretKey
At the header
 - TerminalID

```
  <?php
     $nonce=$randomNum=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 60);

    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp=$date->getTimestamp();
    $httpMethod = "GET";
    $clientId = "YOUR_OWN_ID"; 
    $clientSecretKey = "YOUR_OWN_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY";

    $resourceUrl='https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/categorys';
    $resourceUrl = strtolower($resourceUrl);
    $resourceUrl = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $resourceUrl);
    $encodedUrl = urlencode($resourceUrl);
    $transactionParams = "1";
    $httpMethod = "GET";

    $signatureCipher = $httpMethod . '&' . $encodedUrl . '&' . $timestamp . '&' . $nonce . '&' . $clientId . '&' . $clientSecretKey;

    if (!empty($transactionParams) && is_array($transactionParams)) {
        $parameters = implode("&", $transactionParams);
        $signatureCipher = $signatureCipher . $parameters;
    }
    $signature = base64_encode(sha1($signatureCipher, true));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$resourceUrl);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:InterswitchAuth SUtJQTAzREM3RDY5NUREMzZFQURFNTQxNEE2Nzg1MUJCMUZFQ0Y5MUIxRjg=',           
        'Signature:'.$signature,            
        'Nonce:'.$nonce,            
        'Timestamp:'.$timestamp,            
        'SignatureMethod:SHA1',
        'TerminalID:YOUR_ASSIGNED_TERMINAL_ID'
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $server_output;
    ?>
```

This worked for me, hope it help someone in future